# Epub anchor links opens a browser

Tags: epub3

I am creating an epub with 2 pages.
I have `page_1.xhtml` and `page_2.xhtml`
From `page_1.xhtml` I created a link to `page_2.xhtml` with this code

```
<a href="page_2.xhtml">Page 2</a>
```

But it opens a browser. I only need to redirect to `page_2.xhtml`
They are in the same folder `OEBPS`